# Perl: why Term::Readline spoils STDIN/STDOUT?

Tags: perl, utf-8, readline

If I create new Term::Readline object (and pass binmoded STDIN and STDOUT), input and output get mocked. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use utf8::all;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $X = <>;
chomp $X;
say "õ $X";

my $term = new Term::ReadLine ('test', \*STDIN, \*STDOUT);

say "õ $X";
$X = <>;
chomp $X;
say "õ $X";

__END__
got:
õ
õ õ
� �
õ
� õ
```

If i input characters, which are not present in Latin 1, i get "Wide character" warning and output is better, but still not correct:

```
ž
õ ž
Wide character in print at db.test.pl line 20, <> line 1.
õ ž
ž
� ž
```

How properly set IO when using Term::Readline?

Comment: What's your locale settings? Does everything work without Term::ReadLine? What happens if you create the Term::ReadLine object before you load utf8::all? Go through the normal debugging stuff to isolate the problem.

Comment: A couple of us can't seem to reproduce your error. Can you describe a little bit more about your setup?

Comment: @brian d foy: locale is `et_EE.UTF-8`. Everything works fine when i comment out object creating line. Example above is product of isolating bigger problem. When i `require utf8::all;` after creating object, everything works fine. Which seems strange, because first IO is then made without setting proper encoding.

Comment: @Alex Reynolds: my Perl is 5.12.4 on Kubuntu 11.10, `utf8::all` is 0.002, `Term::Readline` is 1.05, T::RL::Gnu is 1.2. I yesterday upgraded to Kubutu 11.10, before that i had Perl 5.10.1 and it worked. I should try on some other computer too...

Comment: Problem seems in `Term::ReadLine:Gnu`. I tried on similar platform, only without `::Gnu` and everything worked fine. After installing `Term::ReadLine:Gnu` i got faulty behaviour again.

Comment: My correlation to upgrade was wrong, yesterday i installed `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` too and it seem have a bug. All Perl versions i tried work fine without `::Gnu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor adds the 'stdio' layer to the streams which you need to remove. See `:pop` in [PerlIO](http://p3rl.org/PerlIO).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8::all;
use Devel::Peek;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $X = <>;
Dump $X;
chomp $X;
say "õ $X";

say join ' ', PerlIO::get_layers('STDIN');
say join ' ', PerlIO::get_layers('STDOUT');

my $term = new Term::ReadLine ('test', \*STDIN, \*STDOUT);

say join ' ', PerlIO::get_layers('STDIN');
say join ' ', PerlIO::get_layers('STDOUT');

binmode 'STDIN', ':pop';
binmode 'STDOUT', ':pop';

say join ' ', PerlIO::get_layers('STDIN');
say join ' ', PerlIO::get_layers('STDOUT');

say "õ $X";
$X = <>;
Dump $X;
chomp $X;
say "õ $X";

__END__
ž
õ ž
SV = PV(0x753160) at 0x778968
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x766830 "\305\276"\0 [UTF8 "\x{17e}"]
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 80
unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8
unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8
unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8 stdio
unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8 stdio
unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8
unix perlio encoding(utf-8-strict) utf8
õ ž
ž
SV = PV(0x753160) at 0x778968
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x766830 "\305\276\n"\0 [UTF8 "\x{17e}\n"]
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 80
õ ž
```

Comment: It cures the behaviour and you gave me really interesting insight. Thank you! Still, don't you consider such behaviour buggy? I raised a ticket already too.